# struct Cat(string, string, bool, bool)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Tags: c#

Here's my code, I have no idea what is wrong and why does the compiler say that

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

 namespace _11._2
{
class Cat
{
    private string name = "cat";
    private string type = "gizei";
    private bool water = false;
    private bool yalel = false;
    public Cat(string name, string type, bool water, bool yalel);
    public string meow()
    {
        if (yalel)
            return "Meow Meow Meow";
        else
            return "Meow";
    }

    public bool thirsty()
    {
        return water ? true : false;
    }

    public string info()
    {
        return "My name is " + name + " and my type is " + type;
    }
}
}
```

I tried adding abstract or external but the error is still there..

Comment: Try `public Cat(string name, string type, bool water, bool yalel) { /* argument to class member assignment here */}`, that constructor doesn't have a body. You will likely want to assign the arguments to class member fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the following line :

```
public Cat(string name, string type, bool water, bool yalel);
```

This is a constructor declaration, so you have to declare a body for this method :

```
public Cat(string name, string type, bool water, bool yalel)
{
   // Do something like :
   // this.name = name;
   // this.type = type;
   // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public Cat(string name, string type, bool water, bool yalel)
  {

  }
```